# php mysql looking how to check if there are no result

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code

```
require("connession.php");
$contabilita="d";
$dataa="10/12/2018";
$datam_0=explode("/", $dataa);
$datam = "".$datam_0[2];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Max(n_ricevuta)+1 as max_ricevuta 
                            FROM corrispettivi_mod 
                            where anno='$datam' 
                            and contabilita='$contabilita'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
echo $row['max_ricevuta'];
}
else{echo "1";}
```

here is my db

```
data        anno    n_ricevuta  contabilita
2019-12-01  2019    1           nd
```

in my db I have only a row with a value of the filed 'anno' 2019 so it must print '1' but it doesn't.

if I modify in the db the field anno with the value "2018", it works.

help me thanks

Comment: Please show us the contents of your table

Comment: Did I format that correctly?

Comment: I don't know how to format it. if you can help me it will be appreciated

Comment: `$contabilita="d";` but the database has `contabilita = nd` try changing `$contabilita="nd";`

Comment: I'd like it prints also "1" when it doens't find the same value of contabilita. So if anno or contabilita is different from what is inside the db it must print "1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using an aggregate function like `max()` you will always get a row, if there isn't a matching row it will return `null`.

So you need to change your test to...

```
if($row['max_ricevuta'] != null){
    echo $row['max_ricevuta'];
}
else {
    echo "1";
}
```

As RiggsFolly also points out, worth checking the values your using in your testing, you have

```
$contabilita="d";
```

whereas the example data shows `nd`.

Comment: Nigel you may as well add my comment about `$contabilita="d"; but the database has contabilita = nd try changing $contabilita="nd";`  Just to make the answer complete